# How to match this regex in dpath?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I need the regex for the following string in dpath

> the dictionary key starts with 'id' followed by a given number(say 100) followed by
>   forward slash(/)  followed by a hash(#) followed by any number of charecters

I tried 
`dpath.util.search(dictionary1, "id"+str(100)+'/#*')`
but it is returning a empty dictionary

edit:
Here is the repo https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python 
For those who donot know , dpath is a library which enables us to match elements dictionary with a regex.

Comment: @Andrew Kesterson : Please have a look at this

Comment: Can you try by escaping the slash i.e. "id" + str(100) + "\/#.*"?

Comment: I've tried that .. it failed

Comment: I still cannot figure out what you are trying to do here?...and what `regex` has to do with it?...

Comment: @Iron Fist : dpath is a library helpful for specifying a regex instead of explicit key while for accessing values of dictionary .

Answer (score 0):

Probably the regex you are looking for is:

```
/^id\d*\/#.*/
```

where:

- `\d*` means any number of digits (you can use + instead of * if you want at least 1 digit)
- `\/` means forward slash (that bust be escaped)
- `.*` means any number of characters (letters and digits)